# Website Showing IP Not Domain Name

Tags: wordpress, web, web-deployment, domain-name, bluehost

First of all i would like to say that i am more of a designer than a developer.

i have a domain name registered on GoDaddy (www.svelteliving.com) and my hosting is on BLUEHOST.com.

i am now hosting my website but the issues is that the website in the adress bar shows the ip `(http://69.89.31.99/~svelteli/)`  and not the domain name (www.svelteliving.com)

i tried to update my htaccess like below:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.svelteliving\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^69\.89\.31\.99
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.svelteliving.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /~svelteli/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~svelteli/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This seems to work on the homepage only but when i click on a link in the menu the ip shows up again.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .htaccess content with the content below. And, just in case, clear your browser's cache before trying new settings.

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you a lot i will try it in a while .. Fingers crossed

Comment: Hey man, it worked on the home page but when i try to click on any menu item, it directly redirects me to the ip for example when i click on products it goes to this link and displays a 404 error without displaying the page itself [http://69.89.31.99/~svelteli/products/] @hex494D49

Comment: Well, that's a good news :) Now you should check links on your menu, are they relative or maybe absolute. One more thing, check your html, the header section, something like `<base href="http://domain.com/">` and there shouldn't be any ip but your domain name. Anyhow, your .hraccess is now clean and you should check your `base href` and maybe links itself, just in case.

Comment: Sry @hex494D49 i think i will need steps to go through this... if possible and if not i appreciate ur help:) thanks

Comment: YEYYY MAN it worked:) i searched the int more and solved... Proud of myself heheh thank you for your support @hex49D49 :)

Comment: I just saw that you already provided the link of your site and I checked it's source. There are 23 link containing your IP instead of your domain. So, you should open your html / php files and search for your IP and change them. Or maybe Wordpress has an option to do it from the admin, not sure about that. But, I can browse your site. Try to clear your browser's cache.

Comment: Great. I'm really glad :)

Comment: @Pyere Have you ever considered accepting and up-voting my answer since you found it helpful :)

Comment: i am so sorry i didn't mean not to, i think i just didn't notice:) sorry again